# How to make macOS Siri voice read current pasteboard (clipboard) buffer?

Tags: macos, siri, text, accessibility, text-to-speech

While the `System Preferences (Settings)` → `Accessibility` → `Spoken Content` → `Speak selection` is useful, I would very much find it more useful to use Siri voices to read the current contents of the Pasteboard (clipboard).

Is there a way to do this in macOS?

It seems that using Siri voices is very inflexible and so far it's not seemingly possible to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can force it to use the Siri voice, but you can create a shortcut in the Shortcuts app that can speak text from the clipboard. The building blocks in the Shortcuts app are :

1. Get Clipboard
2. Speak

When you add the Speak block it should automatically choose the input from the Get Clipboard action.

Here's an example of what your Shortcut workflow might look like:
[image: Example Shortcut]